# How to Secure Cookie in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, session-cookies

I have an application in MVC which is consuming some third party APIs. While running application on server I am getting below 4 cookies in browser and one of them (OPENIAM_AUTH_TOKEN) is not set secure. So How can I set secure flag and also if you can let me know who might be generating this cookie since in my application it is not mentioned anywhere.

[image]

I have set below in my Web.Config file already :

httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"

Answer (score 0):

You can try add below to your AddCookie

```
Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
```